# Swing mouseEntered strange behavior

Tags: java, swing, mouse

I have a jframe with some JComponents, with some mouseListener. My aim is to show a little jframe with a specified text, when the mouse enter on a jlabel, and to show off it when the mouse is exited.
Jframe is supposed to be shown near the mouse.
Anyway that does not happen, and the programm behaves in a very strange way.
Why?
[the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS0pn.png)
That's my code

```
package finestrina;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class finestra implements MouseListener{

    private JFrame finestra = new JFrame();
    private JFrame pagina = new JFrame();
    private JButton submit1 = new JButton("press");
    private JTextField text = new JTextField();
    finestra(){

        pagina.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pagina.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel cont = new JPanel();
        cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setText("ON MOUSEROVER THIS");
                cont.add(label);
            label.addMouseListener(this);   


            submit1.addMouseListener(this);
            text.addMouseListener(this);

        cont.add(submit1);
        cont.add(text);
        pagina.add(cont);
        pagina.setVisible(true);

        finestra.setUndecorated(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() instanceof JLabel){
            JLabel event_casted = (JLabel)event.getSource();

            if(event_casted.getText().equals("ON MOUSEROVER THIS")){
                Point punto = event.getLocationOnScreen();
                punto.setLocation(punto.getX()+20, punto.getY()+20);

                JLabel littlelabel = new JLabel();

                littlelabel.setText("your mouse is on the jlabel");
                finestra.add(littlelabel);
                finestra.setLocation(punto);
                finestra.setSize(100,100);
                finestra.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() instanceof JLabel){
            JLabel event_casted = (JLabel)event.getSource();
                if(event_casted.getText().equals("ON MOUSEROVER THIS")){
                    finestra.setVisible(false);
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    public static void main(String[] args0){
        new finestra();
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "the program behaves in a strange way" ?

Comment: Ever considered using the `tooltip` support?

Comment: Check the result of (System.out.println(punto.getX()+" " punto.getY());
I think it is returning different than what you expect

Comment: There are number of things going on, when the frame is made visible, focus is removed from the current frame, which is triggering the `mouseExited` event.  The `GridLayout` is causing the label to occupy a large are of the frame, which isn't doing much for positioning of the frame

Comment: @khelwood the label magically disappear, and when the mouse is exited the object finestra is still visible

Comment: `finestra.add(event_casted);` is casing the label to be removed from it's current parent container, as a component can only belong to a single container

Comment: Ok, gridlayout let the label to occupy large space, so the position of "finestra" is not wrong, but how to manage correctly the mousexited event? But why the "label" magically disappear too? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @ElMapoMapo A component may only reside in a single container, the side effect of `finestra.add(event_casted);` is the label is first removed from it's current container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of (possible) issues

- The `GridLayout` will cause the component to occupy most of the space of the container, which might cause the window to "appear" to popup earlier then you expect
- `finestra.add(event_casted);` is causing the label to be removed from it's current parent container (the main window), as a component can only belong to a single container

It would, generally be better to use the tooltip support provided by the API.  Maybe have a look at [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html), remember, they can also support HTML.

If that's not functionality what you want, then maybe a `JPopupMenu` might be better

Comment: Ok @MadProgrammer , you helped me with this, but i started this question, because the real "bug" is when i add some other JComponents to the main window causing the layout to get "magically" broken. I have updated the code...